# Apache NiFi how to check output from each processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to using Apache NiFi, and I trying to create a template that takes a JSON file and turns it into a set of SQL insert statements.

So far I have created a template that takes the JSON file and I have got it to the point of PutSQL. There is no database to connect to at the moment, but what I have not been able to check is the output. Can this be done? What I need to check is whether the array of JSON has been turned into a INSERT per element in the array

Comment: As @mattyb explained, you have control on generating SQL statement if you are using `PutSQL`  and you can observe those by looking at queue content, but in case of  `PutDatabaseRecord` you configure `RecordReader` and it  will internally generate those sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

As far as inpecting the output, what does your flow look like? If you have something like ConvertJSONToSQL -> PutSQL, you can leave PutSQL stopped and run ConvertJSONToSQL, then you will see FlowFile(s) in the connection between the two processors. Then you can right-click on the connection and choose List Queue, then click the "eye" icon on the right for the FlowFile you wish to inspect. That will show you the contents of the FlowFile right before it goes into PutSQL.

Having said all that, if your JSON file contains fields that correspond to columns in your database, consider `PutDatabaseRecord` instead of ConvertJSONToSQL -> PutSQL. That can use a JsonTreeReader to parse each record, and it will generate and execute the necessary SQL as a prepared statement using the values in all records of the FlowFile. That way you don't need to generate the SQL yourself or worry about fragmented transactions or any of that.

Comment: I haven't used convertjsontosql. Some of fields relate to exact fields in the database, others don't. Your point is a good one, is there a way to map fields in JSON to actual fields? Also, the fields are being passed to a stored procedure. In the JSON, there could be an occasional nested array

Comment: Yes you can use JoltTransformJson or JoltTransformRecord to get your fields into a "flat" JSON object, which would be the mapping of fields to columns (and their values)